# Opendaylight - Cannot find symbol getNode()

Tags: java, maven, option-type, opendaylight

I am trying to create a basic Hello-World application in Opendaylight. I created the app by following the steps from https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-magnesium/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html. 
I was able to run basic Hello-World RPC as in the tutorial, and am trying to extend the app so that it can return Netconf Nodes that are present at the equivalent `/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/topology/topology-netconf/`. For this, I am referring to the NCMount Example from https://github.com/opendaylight/coretutorials/tree/master/ncmount.
While trying to do maven build, I am getting the following error:

```
/home/ubuntu/ghost/odlapps/1.3.0-SS/hello/impl/src/main/java/org/opendaylight/hello/impl/HelloWorldImpl.java:[58,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getNode()
[ERROR]   location: class java.util.Optional<org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.tbd.params.xml.ns.yang.network.topology.rev131021.network.topology.Topology>
```

My HelloWorldImpl.java looks like:

```
package org.opendaylight.hello.impl;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.params.xml.ns.yang.hello.rev191127.HelloService;
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.params.xml.ns.yang.hello.rev191127.HelloWorldInput;
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.params.xml.ns.yang.hello.rev191127.HelloWorldOutput;
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.params.xml.ns.yang.hello.rev191127.HelloWorldOutputBuilder;

import org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.common.RpcResult;
import org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.common.RpcResultBuilder;
import org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.binding.InstanceIdentifier;
import org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.common.QName;

import org.opendaylight.mdsal.binding.api.DataBroker;
import org.opendaylight.mdsal.binding.api.ReadTransaction;
import org.opendaylight.mdsal.common.api.LogicalDatastoreType;
import org.opendaylight.mdsal.common.api.ReadFailedException;

import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.netconf.node.topology.rev150114.NetconfNode;
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.netconf.node.topology.rev150114.NetconfNodeConnectionStatus.ConnectionStatus;
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.netconf.node.topology.rev150114.network.topology.topology.topology.types.TopologyNetconf;
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.tbd.params.xml.ns.yang.network.topology.rev131021.NetworkTopology;
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.tbd.params.xml.ns.yang.network.topology.rev131021.NodeId;
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.tbd.params.xml.ns.yang.network.topology.rev131021.TopologyId;
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.tbd.params.xml.ns.yang.network.topology.rev131021.network.topology.Topology;
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.tbd.params.xml.ns.yang.network.topology.rev131021.network.topology.TopologyKey;
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.tbd.params.xml.ns.yang.network.topology.rev131021.network.topology.topology.Node;
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.tbd.params.xml.ns.yang.network.topology.rev131021.network.topology.topology.NodeKey;


public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloService {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorldImpl.class);
    private final DataBroker dataBroker;
    public static final InstanceIdentifier<Topology> NETCONF_TOPO_IID =
            InstanceIdentifier
                    .create(NetworkTopology.class)
                    .child(Topology.class,
                            new TopologyKey(new TopologyId(TopologyNetconf.QNAME.getLocalName())));

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<RpcResult<HelloWorldOutput>> helloWorld(HelloWorldInput input) {

        HelloWorldOutputBuilder helloBuilder = new HelloWorldOutputBuilder();
        ReadTransaction tx = dataBroker.newReadOnlyTransaction();
        List<Node> nodes;

        // Get All nodes from Operational Database
        try {
            nodes = tx.read(LogicalDatastoreType.OPERATIONAL, NETCONF_TOPO_IID)
//                    .checkedGet()
                    .get()
                    .getNode();
        } catch (ReadFailedException e) {
            LOG.error("Failed to read node config from datastore", e);
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Node node : nodes) {
                LOG.info("Node: {}", node);
                NetconfNode nnode = node.augmentation(NetconfNode.class);
                if (nnode != null) {
                        // We have a device
                        ConnectionStatus csts = nnode.getConnectionStatus();
                }
                results.add(node.getNodeId().getValue());
        }

        helloBuilder.setGreeting(results);
        return RpcResultBuilder.success(helloBuilder.build()).buildFuture();
    }
}
```

I am not sure what `org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.tbd.params.xml.ns.yang.network.topology.rev131021.network.topology.Topology` returns because I dont seem to be able to find the apidoc for this package anywhere. I was getting the same error for `getChecked()`, so I commented it out to see if it helps.

So,

1. **Is there any documentation/javadocs that I can refer to understand the Optional that is returned after performing READ on the operational datastore**?
2. **Are there examples based on current archetypes as NCMount is based on pretty old versions of Opendaylight**?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if it says "cannot find symbol getNode()" that can mean one out of two things: the class of which the variable is an instance, doesn't have a getNode() method or it is expecting parameters.

Comment: @Stultuske yes that is obvious. My question is focussed on how can I find what method or parameters to provide.

Comment: You may find the following helpful: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.opendaylight.mdsal/mdsal-docs/latest/org/opendaylight/yang/gen/v1/urn/tbd/params/xml/ns/yang/network/topology/rev131021/network/topology/Topology.html But the compiler error clearly says that you are trying to invoke that method on a `java.util.Optional`. An `Optional<X>` in not an `X`.

Comment: @Holger thank you! I actually did end up finding up docs as well as understood my mistake in understanding the implementation. I am able to build my code now. Running it however seems like a different story haha

Comment: @Holger If you could post your comment as answer, I will accept it as your suggestion helped me solve my issue.